# 2013 Elantra gt will not start

Tags: engine

Car will light up on dashboard as normal no click from engine just will not start up as normal. Checked battery. Fuel in tank. No sound from engine. Went into town shopping came back went to physio came home shut car off open garage went to start car nothing.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've provided, the key is the "no clicking sound". From my experience, this is indicative of the solenoid not at all being engaged in the starter from a bad/going bad battery (low amperage).

Yes, you will see all the lights on the dash, the radio works, the headlights work but the car won't start because those items draw little/low amperage where are the starter draws quite a bit of amperage and the battery's current amperage may be under that required threshold to engage the solenoid and spin over the starter.  Batteries give little to no warning when they are going dead*
(* The starter *may* sound likes it's going "slower" than previous times during starting and the headlights *may* look dimmer when in use.  These are subjective though and again are from my experiences)

I would suggest having the following done:

1. A visual check of both the battery cables (checking for any blatant obvious signs of nicks, cuts, etc...)
2. Remove the battery from your Elantra and get it tested at your local parts store BEFORE TRYING A JUMP START. Reason for this is so that it ensures you're testing the battery in the condition that caused the no-starting issue.
3. Replace battery if needed.

[Additional information on batteries and why the car won't start](https://www.lifewire.com/car-wont-start-but-lights-work-4025730)

Hope this helps!